Tightness of random variables and Borel-Cantelli Lemma
I am solving this task:
Let $\xi_1, \xi_2,...$ be a sequence of random variables defined on the same probability space. Prove that there exists a numeric sequence $c_1, c_2,...$ such that $\xi_n / c_n \to 0$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.
and in it's solution there is a fact about "tightness" of random variable. it is stated as following: $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ to be tight if for all $\epsilon >0$, there is a constant $M$ s.th. $P(|X_n|>M) < \epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I've never seen such a definition before and I'm confused that this fact is given as "definition", not as lemma or exercise. I have not found out how to prove it yet, hence I'm having troubles with my initial exercise. Could you please help me prove this fact about "tightness"?

It's a definition of the term "tight". There is no "fact" in the definition, so there is nothing to "prove".
A sequence $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is said to be tight if the following condition holds: for all $\epsilon >0$, there is a constant $M$ such that $P(|X_n|>M) < \epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
If the given condition does not hold (that is, if for some $\epsilon>0$, there is no constant $M$ with $P(|X_n|>M) < \epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$), then the sequence is not tight.
Some sequences of random variables are tight, and some sequences of random variables are not tight. Perhaps you can come up with some examples.

this definition occurred in this topic I did not get how the author of the first answer got that $m_k(n)$ exists (he stated it as an exercise to be proven, not as definition). Then I came across the definition of "tightness" which sounds just like the fact the author asked reader to prove. I guess I do not understand something, could you please clarify why such $m_k(n)$ exists in the linked topic?

If you would like to ask about that, you should post it as a new question. But basically the point is that for every random variable $X$ and every $\epsilon$, there is some $M$ such that $P(|X|>M)<\epsilon$. (The point of the definition of tightness for a sequence is that we require the same $M$ to work simultaneously for all random variables in the sequence.)

I apology for wrong question format, but my question is just about what you've just written. Why is it right that for every random variable X and every $\epsilon$ there is some M, such that estimation from your message holds? I do not understand how to prove it :///

It's not that the format is wrong, it's that your question is quite different to the one you asked. Go ahead and write a new post about the question you're interested in. It's not best answered in a comments section under an answer to a different question.

As far as a quick answer goes though: you might already be familiar with the same idea in the language of cumulative distribution functions. If $F$ is the c.d.f. of a random variable $X$, i.e. $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$, then $F(x)\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$, and $F(x)\to 0$ as $x\to-\infty$. This is basically the same fact as the one in my comment.
